# Creating a class method __str__

Tags: python

I am working on a program that needs a **str** method. However, when I run the code, it only outputs:

```
What is the name of the pet: Tim
What type of pet is it: Turtle
How old is your pet: 6
```

How can I print out what I need from the str method?
Here is what I have.
***This is the code for my class (classPet.py)***

```
class Pet:
def __init__(self, name, animal_type, age):
    self.__name = name
    self.__animal_type = animal_type
    self.__age = age

def set_name(self, name):
    self.__name = name

def set_type(self, animal_type):
    self.__animal_type = animal_type

def set_age(self, age):
    self.__age = age

def get_name(self):
    return self.__name

def get_animal_type(self):
    return self.__animal_type

def get_age(self):
    return self.__age

def __str__(self):
    return 'Pet Name:', self.__name +\
           '\nAnimal Type:', self.__animal_type +\
           '\nAge:', self.__age
```

***This is the code for my main function (pet.py):***

```
import classPet

def main():
    # Prompt user to enter name, type, and age of pet
    name = input('What is the name of the pet: ')
    animal_type = input('What type of pet is it: ')
    age = int(input('How old is your pet: '))

    pets = classPet.Pet(name, animal_type, age)
    print()

main()
```

Comment: And what did you *expect*? What do you think you're printing?

Comment: Did you... forgot to `print(pets)` ..? You've just done `print()`..

Answer (score 0):

In the code for your main function (pet.py), you are calling print without any parameters. You need to call print with your pet instance as a parameter:

```py
pets = classPet.Pet(name, animal_type, age)
print(pets)  # see here
```

You also need to fix an error in your `__str__` method:
the `__str__` method doesn't concatenate all of its arguments to a string like the `print()` function does it. Instead, it must return a single string.

In your `__str__` method you are seperating your different parts of the string by commas. This will make python think that it's dealing with a tuple. I propose the following solution using pythons `format` function:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "Pet Name: {}\nAnimal Type: {}\nAge: {}".format(self.__name, self.__animal_type, self.__age)
```

The `{}` parts in the string are placeholders that are replaced with the arguments in the parenthesis through the `format` function. They are replaced in order, so the first one is replaced with `self.__name`, etc.

Comment: I get errors when I do that. TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)